# How to update a single value in redis hash

Tags: python, redis, fastapi

I'm using Python FastAPI with redis. I wrote a function to update values in a redis hash, but I couldn't able to update a single value alone, I could only able to re-write the whole hash.

My model:

```
class Item4(BaseModel):
    balance: Optional[float] = None
    currencyCode: Optional[str] = None
    customerId: Optional[int] =None
```

My function:

```
@app.put("/updateBalance/{balanceId}")
async def update_item(item: Item4, balanceId):
    msg = r.hmset(balanceId, dict(item))
    return msg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hmset` is deprecated](https://redis.io/commands/hmset/) for `hset` - but if you want to only update a single key, do not send an hash with all the keys present.

You can [use the `exclude_unset` parameter to Pydantic's `dict()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method to not include any values that hasn't been explicitly provided:

```
r.hmset(balanceId, item.dict(exclude_unset=True))
```